# PDO login system giving errors

Tags: php, pdo

I have a login system using PDO.....I have a class named User with the login functions

Class: User

```
require_once('db.php');

class USER
{

    private $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->connection = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }



    public function doLogin($email,$password)
    {
        try
        {
            $stmt = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email=:email AND password=:password ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':email'=>$email, ':password'=>$password));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
            {
                if(password_verify($password, $userRow['password']))
                {
                    $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['email'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function is_loggedin()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function redirect($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
    }

    public function doLogout()
    {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
        return true;
    }
}
?>
```

Login Page

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("loginsubmit.php");
$login = new USER();

if($login->is_loggedin()!="")
{
    $login->redirect('home.html');
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    if($login->doLogin($email,$password))
    {
        $login->redirect('userprofile.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Wrong Details !";
    }
}
?>
```

I keep getting this error even though the details are correct

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Can someone please help me? Please note I am new to Php, especially OOP and PDO.

Comment: Why are you wrapping PDO in your own database thing? Chances are that's where the issues are coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply PeeHaa...i cant seem to understand what you mean when you say...are you implying the error is coming from my class by the construct with DB connection

Comment: First check whether you're getting `$email` and `$password` inside `doLogin()` method correctly or not.

Comment: That error is from a Query where you are not passing the same number of parameters as you have used parameters in a query. **Guessing its not anything in the code you have shown** That error has a file name and a line number associated with it. **What are they**

Comment: NOTE: Dont fiddle with a users password i.e. `strip_tags`

Comment: AHHH: You are using `password_verify()` after your query!! But you are trying to SELECT the user from your database using a PLAIN-TEXT password as a search criteria. _If you think about that, you should realise it **could not** ever work_ as the password on the database is I ASSUME hashed

Comment: @RiggsFolly you are right....it was trying to verify a hash value but was receiving a plain text password...removed the password_verify and it works

Comment: Except that is not the correct solution. **You must verify the password** thats the point of this code

Comment: Remove the `AND password=:password` from the query and from the `execute(array())` then put the `password_verify()` back in

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually the first answer was right...if i put the password_verify() back in..it gives the same error..but if i bind the password it works